# return focus from iframe to parent

Tags: iframe, focus, keyboard-events

I have some keyboard shortcuts binded to the document object using the keydown event (I am using the jquery.hotkeys plugin to do this, but I doubt this matters).

I then have an iframe which I insert dynamically into the DOM and after some actions remove it. My problem is that after removing the iframe, I need to click back on the parent document in order to be able to use the keyboard shortcuts, otherwise the keydown events are not detected.

I have tried using .focus(), .click(), .mousedown() etc on the document element as well as on other elements on the parent page, but I could not get the focus back to the parent page.

How can I get the focus back to the page without requiring the user to click on the page?
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you find a fix/workarounf for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an iframe that is contained in the document you can store the "main" document as a variable prior to creating the iframe.

Then when you remove the iframe just call top.doc.focus() or top.doc.getElement('id').focus().

Comment: This solution did not work for me, since (I believe) the child script steals focus back to itself before terminating. I've posted the solution that worked for me below.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a while struggling with a similar issue, and what I've concluded is that the script running in the child frame keeps stealing focus back to that frame. Then when the script terminates, the child frame has already been removed, so the browser doesn't know where to focus anymore.

How I solved this was to create a function in the parent (or top) frame, that first removes the child frame, and then restores focus to itself. Now, from the child frame, I simply call the parent's function, and that fixes it.

**Example**:

outer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /></head><body>
    Outer content - press [Enter] to load the iframe
    <div id="iframeHolder"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Create a function for the child frame to call
        function regainFocus(){
            $('iframeHolder').update('');
            window.focus();
        }
        // When the outer document loads, start handling keystrokes
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){ Event.observe(window, 'keyup', function(e){
            // Catch only the Enter key
            if((e.which||window.event.keyCode) != Event.KEY_RETURN) return;

            // Construct the iframe, set its src, add it to holder, and focus on it
            var frame = $(document.createElement('iframe'));
            frame.setAttribute('src', 'inner.html');
            frame.observe('load', function(){ this.contentWindow.focus(); });
            $('iframeHolder').appendChild(frame);
        });});
    </script>
</body></html>
```

inner.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /></head><body>
    Inner content - press [Esc] to close the iframe

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
        // When the inner document loads, start handling keystrokes
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){ Event.observe(window, 'keyup', function(e){
            // Catch only the Esc key
            if((e.which||window.event.keyCode) != Event.KEY_ESC) return;

            // Call the parent's function
            parent.regainFocus();
        });});
    </script>
</body></html>
```